# Python Caesar Cipher - Why is decrypted message output in lowercase?

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I recently tried learning python for the first time and I am also new to encrypting and decrypting stuff.

So I tried this simple python program lets the user encrypt and decrypt messages using the caesar cipher:

```
import string

letters = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase

print("\n \t SENDER")
messange_input = list(input("Enter message to decrypt: ").lower())
message_length = len(messange_input)
key_input = int(input("Enter key input: "))

for i in range(message_length):
    if messange_input[i] == ' ':
        messange_input[i] = ' '
    else:
        message_output = (letters.index(messange_input[i]) + (key_input-1)) % 26
        messange_input[i] = letters[message_output]

print("\nEncrypted Message is:")
print(''.join(map(str, messange_input)))

print("\n \t RECEIVER")
messange_input = list(input("Enter encrypted message: "))
message_length = len(messange_input)
key_input = int(input("Enter key input: "))

for i in range(message_length):
    if messange_input[i] == ' ':
        messange_input[i] = ' '
    else:
        message_output = (letters.index(messange_input[i]) - (key_input-1)) % 26
        messange_input[i] = letters[message_output]

print("\nDecrypted Message is: ")
print(''.join(map(str, messange_input)))
```

my problem is that I can't make it case-sensitive.

here's an example of the program executed:

```
SENDER
Enter message to decrypt: I like Mike
Enter key input: 4

Encrypted Message is:
l olnh plnh

         RECEIVER
Enter encrypted message: l olnh plnh
Enter key input: 4

Decrypted Message is:
i like mike
```

the Decrypted Message should be "I Like Mike", but the output returns the message into all lowercase.

I tried removing the .lower() function but it still doesn't work.

can someone point out where I'm doing it wrong?

Comment: You're transforming the entire input to lower case: `messange_input = list(input("Enter message to decrypt: ").lower())`. Can you explain why?

Comment: One problem (already in encryption code) is the modulo 26 while "letters" contains 52 letters.

Comment: already fixed it. I just had to replace 26 with 52 since I forgot that I added the lowercase and uppercase letters. thanks for the reminder @MichaelButscher